# How to output column data

Tags: perl

I've been trying to output column data for a specific user, but it always seems to not work and it doesn't give me any type of error.

What it should do is get the `UserId` then output that column's data, but in my situation it's actually outputting the user's ID instead of the column data.

```
[08:21:12[PM]][DEBUG] =>> Packet Sent: %xt%up%-1%1%1%
```

The last number 1 is what the method below sends back which is wrong.

```perl
method getColumnsById( $intID, $columns ) {

    my $resQuery = $self->{connection}->prepare( "SELECT $columns FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?" );

    $resQuery->execute( $intID );

    my $arrResult = $resQuery->fetchrow_arrayref( 0 );

    if ( $arrResult ) {
        return $arrResult;
    }
}
```

#### Example:

Username is `Test`, and it selects column `nameglow` then it should display the column data as like `0xFF000... or whatever the user has their column set to.

Comment: What is `[08:21:12[PM]][DEBUG] =>> Packet Sent: %xt%up%-1%1%1%` and how does it relate to your problem? It looks more like a format string that output data. What object-oriented module are you using? `Moo`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it

```
method getColumnsById($intID, $columns) {

        my $resQuery = $self->{connection}->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?");
        $resQuery->execute($intID);
        my $arrResult = $resQuery->fetchrow_hashref;
        if ($arrResult) {
           return $arrResult->{$columns};

        }
}
```

Comment: So the solution is to set `$arrResult` to a hash reference instead? Together with accessing `$self->{connection}`, when you are presumably using an object-oriented framework like `Moo`, you are writing some really scary code here. Just like comments should explain the *why* instead of the *what*, your code should express the *what* instead of the *how*. The last is down to the compiler. Your code is just a bunch of characters that happen to work; you aren't taking advantage of a very high-level language, and much of your work may as well be machine code.